# prove that $x(t) \in ]0,\pi[$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the Cauchy Problem:
$
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}l}
x'(t) = \sin (x(t)),\ t\in\mathbb{R}\\ 
x(0)=x_0 \in ]0,\pi[
\end{array}
\right.
$

I try to prove that $x(t) \in ]0,\pi[ $

What I did:
Using Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, I proved that the Cauchy Problem has a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$

I also proved that the solution cannot be constant since no $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ verifies $x_0=k\pi$.

I don't know to follow-up from there. any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to repeat the proof of the theorem with the iteration method?

Comment: @szw1710: No I didn't. By theorem you mean the subject of my question? Could you please give the name of this iteration method ?

Comment: It is connected with Banach Contraction Principle. I know a theorem I mean as Picard-Lindelof Theorem.

Comment: Yes I tried the Picard-Lindelof Principle but I wasn't able to prove that each term of the Picard series is bounded to $]0,\pi[$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an easy consequence of uniqueness of solutions. The constant functions $0$ and $\pi$ are solutions of the equation. By uniqueness, the graph of the solution with $x(0)\in(0,\pi)$ cannot cross the graph of those constant solutions (otherwise there would be two constant solutions through the same point.) This implies that $0<x(t)<\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sin x,$$ so $$\frac{dx}{\sin x}=dt$$ and the equation is easily solvable in the form $t=\varphi(x).$ You can now find a domain of $\varphi$ taking into account the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you! I find : $t= \ln(\tan x))$. But how to go from there? Is the domain of definition of $\ln$ is enough to justify that $x(t) \in ]0,\pi[$?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the explicit solution. Probably that will help you investigate the values of $x(t)$. 
$$x'(t)=\sin x(t)\Rightarrow x''(t)=\cos x(t)\cdot x'(t)=\cos x(t)\sin x(t)$$
On the other hand
$$x'(t)^2=\sin x(t) x'(t)\Rightarrow \int x'(t)^2\,dt=\int \sin x(t) x'(t)\,dt$$
But
$$\int \sin x(t) x'(t)\,dt=\int\sin x(t)\,dx(t)=-\cos x(t)+C$$
and after several steps of integration by parts we get
$$\int x'(t)^2\,dt=\int x'(t)\,d x(t)=x'(t)x(t)-\int x(t)x''(t)\,dt\\
=x'(t)x(t)-\int \cos x(t) x(t)x'(t)\,dt=x'(t)x(t)-\int\cos x(t)x(t)\,d x(t)\\
=x'(t)x(t)-\frac{1}{2}x^2(t)\cos x(t)-\frac{1}{2}\int x^2(t)\sin x(t)\,dt\\=x'(t)x(t)-\frac{1}{2}x^2(t)\cos x(t)-\frac{1}{2}\int x^2(t)\,dx(t)\\
=x(t)\sin x(t)-\frac{1}{2}x^2(t)\cos x(t)-\frac{1}{6}x^3(t)$$
Overall we get
$$x(t)\sin x(t)-\frac{1}{2}x^2(t)\cos x(t)-\frac{1}{6}x^3(t)=-\cos x(t)+C$$
where $C$ is uniquely determined by $x(0)=x_0$ and equals
$$C=x_0\sin x_0-\frac{1}{2}x^2_0\cos x_0-\frac{1}{6}x^3_0+\cos x_0$$

Comment: I can't see the explicit solutiin : x function of t

Comment: well yes it is not exactly telling you what $x(t)$ is but still it can provide you with some information. For instance the right side is bounded since $\cos x$ is bounded this implies that the left side must be bounded so $x(t)\in(a,b)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: indeed, thank you!